# Extract data from many PDF forms

Tags: forms, unix, pdf, adobe

I regularly receive large numbers of the same PDF form. I want to extract the data from them into a text file. I'd like to do this via a script of some sort. I'm working in a UNIX environment.

Is this possible?  I've googled my brains out and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Text in PDF is represented by text elements in page content streams. The streams are commonly compressed. If you have the time and resources you can use ISO 32000-1:2008 or Adobe PDF 1.7 specification to build your own PDF parser. Or it may be more practical to use a 3rd party app as an intermediate translation step.

There are utilities that will decode the stream and give you clear text. One option is PDFtk Server which will work in your environment. Another option is to use the Poppler PDF Rendering Library which has a command line utility "pdftotext" useful for searching for strings in PDFs.

Comment: The op talked about PDF forms. PDF form contents are **not** part of the page content. Thus, extracting page content won't help. That of course is said assuming the op means PDF forms according to the specification...

Comment: Sadly, I don't have many of the open source tools installed on the server, and can't have them installed.

I have discovered that this is very possible to do this extraction in Excel using VBA along with some Acrobat libraries.  Sadly, this doesn't help me in my problem, but the Excel solution is pretty easy.